# Magento2.3.0 In product edit go to advance pricing there calender icon not proper showing

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.3.0, design, calendar

I am using Magento2.3.0 and go to admin side product edit inside advance pricing  there special price inside calender icon not proper showing please if you have any idea how to resolve it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below url :

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/18627

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18605

for above url, its related to your issue and fixed from magento team.

I hope its very helpful to you.